# Setting polygon style with setStyle() function in Leaflet does not work from select menu

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I think this question will be easy for you
But I don't know where is the problem

I am trying to change the style of the rectangle using the select menu but it does not happen

In contrast, when using the buttons, the change is done

code in "codepen"
https://codepen.io/A_Abdelwahed/pen/yLYoPqj

```
<body>
    <button id="style2" style="position: absolute;z-index: 999;" >style2</button><br>
    <button id="style3" style="position: absolute;z-index: 999;" >style3</button><br>
    <button id="style4" style="position: absolute;z-index: 999;" >style4</button><br>
    <select id="selectDataType" style="position: absolute;z-index: 999;" ></select>
    <div id="mapcontainer"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>

        // create map
        //var myMap = L.map("mapcontainer").setView([30.06263, 31.24967], 15);

        var myMap = L.map('mapcontainer', {
            center: [30.2, 30.2],
            zoom: 7,
            zoomControl:false
        });

        // create Basemap
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(myMap);

        // create a red polygon from an array of LatLng points
        var latlngs = [[30.1, 30.1],[30.1, 30.9],[30.9, 30.9],[30.9, 30.1]];
        var style = {fillColor:'red',color: 'black',weight:2,fillOpacity:0.8}
        var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, style ).addTo(myMap);


        var style2 = {fillColor:'green',color: 'black',weight:2,fillOpacity:0.8}
        document.getElementById("style2").onclick = function (){
            polygon.setStyle(style2);
        }

        var style3 = {fillColor:'gray',color: 'black',weight:2,fillOpacity:0.8}
        document.getElementById("style3").onclick = function (){
            polygon.setStyle(style3);
        }

        var style4 = {fillColor:'blue',color: 'black',weight:2,fillOpacity:0.8}
        document.getElementById("style4").onclick = function (){
            polygon.setStyle(style4);
        }


        // array list to create select menu
        var dataforchange =[{selectMenuValue:"red",myStyle:"style1"},
                           {selectMenuValue:"green",myStyle:"style2"},
                           {selectMenuValue:"gray",myStyle:"style3"},
                           {selectMenuValue:"blue",myStyle:"style4"}
                          ]

        // code to put color name in select menu
        var selectDataType = document.getElementById('selectDataType');
        for (var i=0; dataforchange.length > i ; i=i+1){
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.textContent = dataforchange[i].selectMenuValue;
            selectDataType.appendChild(option);
        };

        //code to do action with change select menu
        selectDataType.addEventListener("change",function(){
        'use strict';
        var z = selectDataType.options[selectDataType.selectedIndex].index;
            var newStyle = dataforchange[z].myStyle;
             alert(newStyle);
            polygon.setStyle(newStyle);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the statement `var newStyle = dataforchange[z].myStyle;` you are retrieving style name as a string, but for setting style with `polygon.setStyle(newStyle);` you need style object.

Solution is to create an array with all styles and then retrieve style from there:

```
style = [style, style2, style3, style4];

selectDataType.addEventListener("change",function(){
  'use strict';
  var z = selectDataType.options[selectDataType.selectedIndex].index;
  polygon.setStyle(style[z]);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much
It worked